Loop buzzer through 12khz too 20kz and show on LCD 1602 display with breadboard button and serial cmd
Well the title is the summary of my setup and its to see if it cancels out my tinnitus lol it actually does :)
well I made progress with what you said, I can turn on my LED and loop through the Hz on the buzzer and LCD with the use of a serial command like "on 15000 200 20 255". The breadboard button also turns off and on if it gets too loud. It still doesnt like the python script for DOS cmd line though.
please help.
This is my updated code:
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

const int ledPin = 13;  // Pin connected to the LED (built-in LED)
const int buttonPin = 2;
const int buzzerPin = 9;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
long interval = 100;
int frequency = 12000;
int duration = 10;
int volume = 128;
bool buttonPressed = false;
bool buzzerActive = false;  // Initialized only once

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  // Set the LED pin as an output
  Serial.begin(9600);  // Start serial communication at 9600 baud rate
  Serial.println("Enter 'on' followed by parameters (frequency, interval, duration, volume) to turn the LED, LCD, and buzzer on, and 'off' to turn them off.");
  Serial.println("Example: on 15000 200 20 255");

  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Hz: OFF");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Ear pop MH help");

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
}

void led_lcd_buzzer_change(String command) {
  Serial.println("Received command: " + command);  // Echo the received command
  
  command.trim();  // Remove any trailing whitespace
  if (command.startsWith("on")) {
    // Parse additional parameters if present
    int firstSpace = command.indexOf(' ');
    if (firstSpace != -1) {
      String params = command.substring(firstSpace + 1);
      int secondSpace = params.indexOf(' ');
      if (secondSpace != -1) {
        frequency = params.substring(0, secondSpace).toInt();
        params = params.substring(secondSpace + 1);
        int thirdSpace = params.indexOf(' ');
        if (thirdSpace != -1) {
          interval = params.substring(0, thirdSpace).toInt();
          params = params.substring(thirdSpace + 1);
          int fourthSpace = params.indexOf(' ');
          if (fourthSpace != -1) {
            duration = params.substring(0, fourthSpace).toInt();
            volume = params.substring(fourthSpace + 1).toInt();
          } else {
            duration = params.toInt();
          }
        } else {
          interval = params.toInt();
        }
      } else {
        frequency = params.toInt();
      }
    }
    
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  // Turn the LED on
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("                ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Hz: ON");
    Serial.println("Hz is ON");

    buzzerActive = true;
    tone(buzzerPin, frequency, duration);  // Start the buzzer with current settings
    lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
    lcd.print(frequency);
    lcd.print("Hz  ");
    Serial.println("Buzzer started with frequency: " + String(frequency) + ", interval: " + String(interval) + ", duration: " + String(duration) + ", volume: " + String(volume));

  } else if (command == "off") {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  // Turn the LED off
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("                ");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Hz: OFF");
    Serial.println("Hz: is OFF");

    buzzerActive = false;
    noTone(buzzerPin);
    lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
    lcd.print("Off       ");
    Serial.println("Buzzer Off");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Invalid command. Please enter 'on' with parameters or 'off'.");
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {  // Check if there's any data available from the serial port
    String command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');  // Read the incoming string until a newline character
    command.trim();  // Remove any trailing whitespace
    led_lcd_buzzer_change(command);  // Call the function and pass the command
  }

  // Handle button press
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) {
    buttonPressed = false;
  } else if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW && !buttonPressed) {
    delay(50); // Debounce the button press
    buttonPressed = true;
    if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW) {
      if (digitalRead(ledPin) == HIGH) {
        led_lcd_buzzer_change("off");
      } else {
        led_lcd_buzzer_change("on");
      }
      delay(250); // Prevent rapid toggling
    }
  }

  // Handle the buzzer frequency update if it is active
  if (buzzerActive) {
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      tone(buzzerPin, frequency, duration);
      lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
      lcd.print(frequency);
      lcd.print("Hz  ");
      frequency += 100;
      if (frequency > 20000) {
        frequency = 12000;
      }
    }
  }
}

DOS just exits.
Python script:
import serial
import time
import argparse

# Set up the serial port (adjust the port name as necessary)
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)  # Use the correct COM port for your system

def send_command(command):
    print(f"Sending command: {command}")
    ser.write((command + '\n').encode())  # Ensure command ends with newline
    time.sleep(0.1)  # Small delay to ensure the command is processed

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Control Arduino via serial commands.")
    parser.add_argument("action", choices=["on", "off"], help="Action to perform: on or off")
    parser.add_argument("--frequency", type=int, default=12000, help="Frequency in Hz")
    parser.add_argument("--interval", type=int, default=100, help="Interval in ms")
    parser.add_argument("--duration", type=int, default=10, help="Duration in ms")
    parser.add_argument("--volume", type=int, default=128, help="Volume (0-255)")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.action == "on":
        command = f"{args.action} {args.frequency} {args.interval} {args.duration} {args.volume}"
    else:
        command = args.action

    send_command(command)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


reduce your code to simply turn on an LED when the serial command is received

that was a good idea, just done that, now building up from that :)

well I made progress with what you said, I can turn on my LED and loop through the Hz on the buzzer and LCD with the use of a serial command like "on 15000 200 20 255". The breadboard button also turns off and on if it gets too loud. It still doesnt like the python script for DOS cmd line start though.

its okay, got it working :)
